# Is ture that $L/K$ is normal extension?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Considering a field tower $K \subset E \subset L $, $E/K$ is separable extension,$L/E$ is normal extension, is ture that $L/K$ is normal extension?

Comment: I know that a tower of  fields $K \subset E \subset L$,if $L/E$ is normal, $E/K$ is normal,but $L/K$ is possible not normal. But now what I want to ask is if $L/E$ is normal, $E/K$ is separable,how is $L/K$?

Comment: The answer to the linked question adresses this question as well

Answer (score 1):

No: consider e.g. $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt{5})$.